# How to capture iframe nested within Shadow DOM's "#shadow-root (open)" element?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

- I need to inject an element inside an `<iframe>`, after a `<button>` within this iframe is clicked.
- This `<iframe>`exists within a page (e. g. somewebpage.com) that is not under my control.
- The `<iframe>`'s content belongs to the same domain as the main document's body/DOM structure.
- To achieve this I need to use a Content Script file from a Chrome Extension as per the below V3 manifest's `"content_scripts"` configuration:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "type": "module",                // I added this items "type", "run_at", "all_frames"
            "run_at": "document_end",        // and "match_origin_as_fallback" hoping they  
            "all_frames": true,              // would help.
            "match_origin_as_fallback": true, 
            "js": [
                "foreground.js"               // File containing the pure JS code
            ],
            "matches": [
                "https://somewebpage.com/*"   // The page where I want to inject the element
            ]
```

The extension's content script `"foreground.js"` file contains the code that should detect the iframe, listen to the `click` event, and then inject the element within the iframe after `click` is detected.

After the page is fully loaded, when I inspect the elements on this page, it basically looks like this:

```
<body>
    <macroponent>
        #shadow-root (open) <!-- Shadow DOM element. I believe this is what is my main obstacle -->
        <div>
            <sn-canvas-appshell-root>
                <sn-canvas-appshell-layout>
                    <sn-polaris-layout>
                        <iframe id="myIframe"> <!-- to access button I need to find the iframe 1st -->
                            <button id="myButton">TAKE</button> <!-- I need to get that click event -->
                        </iframe>
                    </sn-polaris-layout>
            </sn-canvas-appshell-root>
            </sn-canvas-appshell-root>
        </div>
    </macroponent> 
</body>
```

I have tried a lot of different approaches and none were able to find the `<iframe>`. The error messages on the console are returning the `getElementById` as `null` and `getElementsByTagName` as `undefined`.

As a standard method I tried this with some variations like `window.onload`:

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert("Hurray!");
            // Injected element code here
        });
    }
```

I have also tried some more advanced solutions like this:

```
function searchFrame(id) {                                     // id = the id of the wanted (i)frame
    var result = null,                                         // Stores the result
        search = function (iframes) {                          // Recursively called function
            var n;                                             // General loop counter
            for (n = 0; n < iframes.length; n++) {             // Iterate through all passed windows in (i)frames
                if (iframes[n].frameElement.id === id) {       // Check the id of the (i)frame
                    result = iframes[n];                       // If found the wanted id, store the window to result
                }
                if (!result && iframes[n].frames.length > 0) { // Check if result not found and current window has (i)frames
                    search(iframes[n].frames);                 // Call search again, pass the windows in current window
                }
            }
        };
    search(window.top.frames);                                  // Start searching from the topmost window
    return result;                                              // Returns the wanted window if found, null otherwise
}
```

**Source:**

[Get element value inside iframe which is nested inside Frame in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074694/get-element-value-inside-iframe-which-is-nested-inside-frame-in-javascript/)

In my opinion, this issue persists perhaps because the `<iframe>` is a child to a **"Shadow DOM"** element, which makes the method of finding the `<iframe>` different from the standard.

After realizing that probably the issue is that the `<iframe>` is a child to a **"Shadow DOM"**  element, I tried this approach from another question:

```
this.windows = this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName('app-window')
```

**Source:**

[GetElementById from within Shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101967/getelementbyid-from-within-shadow-dom)

Or even this one:
(although I suspect it might be a bit overkill for my use case)

```
customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = `<slot></slot>`;
  }
})

const shadowDive = (
  el,
  selector,
  match = (el, root) => {
    console.warn('match', el, root);
  },
  root = el.shadowRoot || el
) => {
  root.querySelector(selector) && match(root.querySelector(selector), root);
  [...root.querySelectorAll("*")].map(el => shadowDive(el, selector, match));
}
shadowDive(document.body, "content"); // note optional parameters
```

**Source:**

[How to select element tag from shadow root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267809/how-to-select-element-tag-from-shadow-root)

And again I am getting the same `null` or `undefined` errors.
But I think that perhaps I am on the right track now that I know that the `<iframe>` is nested within a **"Shadow DOM"** element.

Perhaps there is a way to bypass or respect the **"Shadow DOM"** and get to that `<iframe>` but to be honest I am out of ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A shadowRoot doesn't have `getElementsByTagName`.
2. ShadowDOM frames aren't exposed in the global `window` or `frames` (it's the same thing BTW)
3. customElements.define doesn't work inside content scripts (due to "world isolation").

You can use querySelector + contentDocument:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('macroponent').shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe');
const elInner = el.contentDocument.querySelector('div');
```

Note that you don't need `all_frames` or `match_origin_as_fallback` here because the iframe is same-origin, hence it's directly accessible from the main document's content script as shown above.

**One pitfall** is that modern sites generate the contents of the page dynamically, often depending on a network response, which can happen long time after all your content scripts ran. In this case you can use MutationObserver to detect it or simply re-check periodically inside setInterval.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm Thanks that worked! I used the first line. Not sure what the 2nd line is supposed to do. I used below that 1st line, this: ```el.contentDocument.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", funtion() {...```