Customized Chrome extension context menu inconsistently appearing in all input fields?
I'm facing an issue with my Chrome extension's context menu functionality, particularly in relation to ServiceNow input fields. The context menu works as intended for some input fields but fails to paste content for others, especially within the ServiceNow platform or Reddit.
(I have created a context menu to paste in my customized texts by having different menu items with finished texts)


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Extension installed");
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "pasteOption1",
    title: "Hämta datorn",
    contexts: ["editable"]
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  console.log("Context menu clicked:", info, tab);
  if (info.menuItemId === "pasteOption1" && tab) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: pasteCustomText,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Script executed successfully"))
    .catch(error => console.error("Error executing script:", error));
  }
});

function pasteCustomText() {
  const targetElement = document.activeElement;
  console.log("Target element:", targetElement);
  
  const tagName = targetElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
  
  if (tagName === "textarea" || tagName === "input") {
    // For textarea and input elements, modify the value property
    targetElement.value += " Hi! We will put the goods in a locker. An email with pick-up information will be sent separately.";
  } else if (targetElement.isContentEditable) {
    // For contentEditable elements, use textContent
    targetElement.textContent += " Hi! We will put the goods in a locker. An email with pick-up information will be sent separately.";
  } else {
    console.error("Unsupported input type:", tagName);
    // Handle unsupported input types gracefully here
    // For example, you can display a message to the user or simply do nothing
  }
}



Debugging gives me these responses where my code cannot handle to paste in the inputs:

Unsupported input type: REDDIT-SEARCH-LARGE (from Reddit search large input field)
Unsupported input type: iframe (from commenting in Reddit)
Unsupported input type: macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010 (component object or ID)
These responses provide more specific details about the unsupported input types encountered in different scenarios, including Reddit search, commenting on Reddit, and a component object or ID inside servicenow.

Note: This issue seems to not have an easy answer for many years now. Please explain so that others can take part of this. Because chrome or edge documentation need better improvement
Resources:
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40375229
Is there a flexible way to modify the contents of an editable element?


Add frameId: info.frameId to target object, 2) Accessing the contents won't work with custom elements, so try using the deprecated document.execCommand, example.


I created this extension using the code you provided and tested it on both Edge and Chrome. It works fine in other input fields, but not on reddit (search bar or comment). You can press "Alt+Shift+I" to submit feedback in Edge.

@wOxxOm It works now for the inpt fields in reddit. I have updated the code. Still experiencing a issue with servicenow though. Service now is created with angular js and the response when focusing on input element gives component id that seems embedded inside shadow root open

@wOxxOm will try your solution here for anyone else watching this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225479/how-to-capture-iframe-nested-within-shadow-doms-shadow-root-open-element

Still not working
